# Moving shapes on a tkinter canvas using keyboard input

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm trying to make a shape move on a tkinter canvas, but get an error message

when I press "s". The circle should move down but I just receive an error. What does the error mean and how do i fix it?

Here's my code:

```
from tkinter import *

#circles 1st set of quads - c for circle x/y for x or y 1 for 1st set
global cx1
cx1 = 10
global cy1
cy1 = 10


# circles second set of quads
global cx2
cx2 = 90
global cy2
cy2 = 90


root = Tk()
root.title("jump")

game = Canvas(root, width = 1000, height = 1000)
game.pack()

ship11 = game.create_oval(cx1, cy1, cx2, cy2, fill = "black")
ship12 = game.create_polygon((50, 10, 15, 70, 85, 70), fill="red")

def down(zero) :
    game.move(ship11, cx1, cy1 + 100, cx2, cy2 + 100)
    print("down")

root.bind("s", down)
```

This is the error:

```
    >>> Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/idlelib/run.py", line 125, in main
    seq, request = rpc.request_queue.get(block=True, timeout=0.05)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/queue.py", line 172, in get
    raise Empty
queue.Empty

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1562, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/jump.py", line 27, in down
    game.move(ship11, cx1, cy1 + 100, cx2, cy2 + 100)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2443, in move
    self.tk.call((self._w, 'move') + args)
_tkinter.TclError: wrong # args: should be ".1979928560 move tagOrId xAmount yAmount"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to move the canvas with too many arguments. According to the [TKinter documentation](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.move-method), `move()` has only three arguments: `move(item, dx, dy)`.

Here is a working version of the `down()` method that moves `ship11` down 100 units:

```
def down(zero) :
    dx = 0
    dy = 100
    game.move(ship11, dx, dy)
    print("down")
```

Comment: this wont change the shapes sides and it will look the same wont it?

Comment: No, the shapes will not rotate with this. And if you call `game.move()` twice on two different shapes, I believe it will achieve the same.